# Webpack ignore dynamic import in dependency

Tags: javascript, webpack, create-react-app

I currently maintain two packages, one is a library and the other is a craco app. Within the library, I want to preserve a dynamic import statement:

```js
// library.js
export async function getExternalModule(expression) {
  const { stuff } = await import('http://someserver/' + expression)
  return stuff
}
```

```
// craco.tsx
import { getExternalModule } from 'library';

const x = await getExternalModule('some-code.js')
```

When I run this code in the browser, I always get a `cannot find module 'http://someserver/some-code.js'.`

I've already tried:

```js
// craco.config.js
webpack.resolve.alias = {
  'http://someserver': false
}

webpack.plugins = [
  new webpack.IgnorePlugin({
    resourceRegExp: /http:\/\/someserver/
  })
]

webpack.externals = {
  'http://someserver': 'http://someserver'
}
```

I know that Webpack provides for ways to specify which import expressions to ignore using magic comments, but as far as I can tell those only work if the import statement is in the craco app itself and doesn't work within dependencies

Is there some way I can get webpack to ignore that specific import statement, or perhaps is there a better way to go about what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I settled on using the function constructor, i.e `new Function('path', 'return import(path)')`.

This won't work with testing frameworks such as Jest and may need attention for NodeJS, but for the browser it suffices.